# Canvas drawImage type error on Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a weird bug on the lastest chrome (v27 on Windows 7) using Canvas and drawImage. The bug only occur on Chrome, everything works as expected on Firefox and IE.

I created a failing reduce test case here: http://jsfiddle.net/qU3s5/

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
}
img.src = "http://octodex.github.com/images/foundingfather_v2.png";
```

This give me `Uncaught TypeError: Type error` on the line where `drawImage` is called.

Comment: that jsfiddle worked for me...try changing the id name to something more unique

Comment: I wonder if this can be triggered by an experimental Chrome feature in `about:flag`... That's definitly not working for me on Windows 7

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apparently Chrome throw an error when using `new Image()`. You have to use this instead:

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aM8aA/

Here's the related Chromium project bug report: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=238071

Comment: +1 Wow: Good info to have...but very disturbing!  The latest Chrome versions seem to be glitching quite often regarding canvas.

Comment: It might not be that chrome is having more glitches, but that more people are using it so that more glitches are being found.